# Making video content for 30' x 10' 3:1 Widescreen

Tags: editing, projector, output, scale, presentation

Looking for some help on how content should be created for an upcoming show with super widescreen blend on it.

The show consists of a 30' x 10' front projection screen with unblended resolution of 3840 x 1080. Video content is currently being created, as the projectors are being blended there is a 600px overlap, the resulting width is 3240px.

Should I get the content made in 3240px or 3840px?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since the resulting projected image is 3240 px wide, that's the size you should create. Then output two "halves" -- the leftmost 1920 px, then the rightmost 1920 px. There will be 600 px that appear in both parts. That's the overlap.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the play out and display system but generally, using Adobe After Effects, make a comp the full size of the raster, then render out a half size left projector and half size right projector. The blending will be done at the vertical intersection. So comp at 3840x1080, two half comps at 1920x1080 for each of the two sides. I would suggest talking to the display technician to be sure.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm downvoting you because this answer is wrong. You lose 600px from the middle where the blend is, because the two projectors overlap. The total width of the comp should be 3240. But good call for "talking to the technician". That is the best approach.